# Cannot remove selected class from UL LI list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My jQuery code doesn't appear to be working. Perhaps a fresh set of eyes can take a look over for me. I am failing at attempting to remove the previous classname "selected" once a new LI item has been clicked on. However, in the pic below, it seems to not be working:

[image]

Here is the jQuery Code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".field_arrow").click(function() {

        $(".field_list").css("display", "block");

    });

    $(".field_list li").click(function(e) {

        var select = $(this).closest('.field_list')

        select.find("ul li").removeClass('selected');

        $(this).addClass('selected');

    });

}); 
</script>
```

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
}
.field_container {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 177px;
}
.field_wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.field_arrow {
    background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
    width:20px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.field_arrow:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.field {
    border: 0;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.field_list {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
}
.field_list li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;
}
.field_list li:hover {
    background: red;
}
.selected {
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".field_arrow").click(function() {

        $(".field_list").css("display", "block");

    });

    $(".field_list li").click(function(e) {

        var select = $(this).closest('.field_list')

        select.find("ul li").removeClass('selected');

        $(this).addClass('selected');

    });

}); 
</script>

<div class="field_container">

    <div class="field_wrapper"><input type="text" class="field"></div>

    <div class="field_arrow"></div>

    <ul class="field_list">
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Oranges</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
    </ul>


<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<head>` is never closed. Your `</body>` never starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field_list` is the `ul` so you don't need the `ul` selector when finding the `li`s inside it. Try this:

```
select.find("li").removeClass('selected');
```

And if you only have one `li` selected at once you can just find the single one that currently has the class like this instead of attempting to remove the class from every `li` when only one will have it at a time:

```
select.find(".selected").removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using `siblings()` since you are trying to remove class `selected` from rest of the `li` and apply it to the current one..

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Here's an example : **http://jsfiddle.net/mj1u0qa2/**